# Using package nomencl

Tags: nomenclature

I have used the package `nomencl`. In my code I have incorporated the `\nomenclature` as well. But when I compile, it is not showing me any results. My code is :

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
---page numbering and other things included-----
\include{symbols}
-----others---
\end{document}
```

#### symbols.tex

```
\chapter*{NOTATIONS}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Notations}
\nomenclature{$G_e$}{Equivalent Shear Modulus}
\printnomenclature
```

Shall I use `\nomenclature` while explaining the chapter. Will It give me the same results? like

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
---page numbering and other things included-----
\include{symbols}
\include{chap3-calculate_w}
-----others---
\end{document}
```

#### symbols.tex

```
\chapter*{NOTATIONS}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Notations}
\printnomenclature
```

#### chap3-calculate_w.tex

```
\chapter{SETTLEMENT RESPONSE OF GEOSYNTHETIC REINFORCED GRANULAR FILL SOFT SOIL}
\label{chap:W}
\section{INTRODUCTION}
In this thesis, the methodology to determine an  Equivalent single layer shear modulus \nomenclature{$G_e$}{Equivalent Shear Modulus},$G_e$ value for a...etc
```

I am not getting the output in both these. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please edit your MWE and format the code block by selecting it and clicking on the `{}` symbol. Thanks.  Also, review your earlier questions and accept any answers that were helpful to you.

Comment: After running LaTeX, did you run `makeindex <filename>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <filename>.els`, and then rerun LaTeX?

Comment: Since you are using `TeXMaker` you need to define the sequence of commands used by the `Quick Build` command via the `Configure Texmaker` dialog to include the above mentioned options to `makeindex`.

Comment: I'd just like to add that I had a similar issue, and it turned out to be a problem caused by using \pagenumbering{gobble} - a command that "eated up" the nomenclature section in the compiled document.

Comment: pretty much what @PeterGrill proposed (I guess). Do not forget to make the index (Tools -> Index). After this, the Nomenclature list was made for me.

Answer (score 30):

The [`nomencl` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nomencl/nomencl.pdf) explicitly states the compile sequence in order to use the package:

```
latex <filename>.tex
makeindex <filename>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <filename>.nls
latex <filename>.tex
```

If you're using `pdflatex`, the same sequence holds. After following this sequence, your nomenclature chapter is printed, as expected:

[image: Nomenclature]

Comment: I'm sorry I can't get it. I compiled using pdflat and then quick builded it. But I am not getting the results.

Comment: You need to compile using `pdflatex`, then run `makeindex`, then run `pdflatex` again. What does `quick build` mean?

Comment: Kind of annoying - but I guess one can build this into your compile commands.

Comment: @ForkrulAssail arara aside, this can be [integrated with latexmk](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105943/latexmk-and-nomencl)

Comment: There is a [good script](https://gist.github.com/Sciss/9fd5ac76d9b60c7d1bd3) at Github that includes the nomenclature run. Additionally it cleans out old files beforehand, creating a clean build. `biber` can be switched for `bibtex` in the script, if desired.

Answer (score 13):

[`arara`](https://github.com/cereda/arara) has a predefined `nomencl` rule, so you can use (from the [`nomencl` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/nomencl)) the following directives:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\section*{Main equations}

\begin{equation}
a=\frac{N}{A}
\end{equation}%

\nomenclature{$a$}{The number of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$N$}{The number of angels per needle point}%
\nomenclature{$A$}{The area of the needle point}%

The equation $\sigma = m a$%
\nomenclature{$\sigma$}{The total mass of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$m$}{The mass of one angel}
follows easily.

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

Running `arara`:

```
$ arara mydoc.tex
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Running PDFLaTeX... SUCCESS
Running Nomencl... SUCCESS
Running PDFLaTeX... SUCCESS
```

The output:

[image: Output]

Comment: would you please specify how we can transform this one-column nomenclature to a  two-columns nomenclature? That is, how we can move the  fourth and fifths columns of the nomenclature to a second column which stands at the right hand side of the first column?

Answer (score 7):

Using kile, I have configured the QuikBuild command as follows:

go to: Settings -> Configure Kile... -> Build

create a new tool:

- Name: "MakeIndexNomencl"
- Command: makeindex
- Options: '%S.nlo' -s nomencl.ist -o '%S.nls'

add MakeIndexNomencl and a second PDFLaTeX to the QuickBuild tool:

- PDFLaTeX
- MakeIndexNomencl
- PDFLaTeX

Answer (score 4):

This may have been answered sufficiently elsewhere, but I configured TeXmaker to do this automatically by adding the following line of code to the makeindex. I imagine it maybe possible to do something similar in other editors.

Go to;

options,

Configure TeXmaker,

then in the makeindex box add

`%.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.els`

to the end of whatever is already in the box, separated by a space.

I am using TeXmaker under windows 7 and this worked for me, hopefully its helpful.

Comment: The answer of James worked for me, with different settings.
Options > Configure TeXmaker > in the makeindex box: makeindex %.idx %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls

Answer (score 2):

I have spent a fair time struggling with this one as well.
It seemed as if the devil was in the details, i.e. the file endings in the makeindex and makeglossary commands.

For some reason I cannot explain, my approach did not work until after I included the packages `index` and `glossaries` as well as their respective `makeindex`, `makeglossary`, `printindex` and `printglossary`.
I also added the following line in the commands setup:

> sh -c "PATH=$PATH:/usr/texbin/; makeglossaries %.nls"

After that I got the actual Nomenclature output, and for some reason it still worked after removing all the index/glossary commands and packages from the latex-file.
[image: Nomenclature]

The code is the usual nomenclature sample code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{nomencl} 

\makenomenclature

\begin{document} 
    \section*{Main equations} 
    \begin{equation}
        a=\frac{N}{A}
    \end{equation}

\nomenclature{$a$}{The number of angels per unit area}% 
\nomenclature{$N$}{The number of angels per needle point}% 
\nomenclature{$A$}{The area of the needle point}%
The equation $\sigma = m a$%
\nomenclature{$\sigma$}{The total mass of angels per unit area}% 
\nomenclature{$m$}{The mass of one angel}
follows easily.

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

As mentioned before, you have to fix your Index command in your LaTeX program's settings/preferences:
In TeXstudio this is done under "preferences -> commands".
Note the blue icon to the right of some commands, it indicates that this command is run twice.

[image: Commands]

**MakeIndex:**

> /usr/texbin/makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls

You can test the result of this command by forcing it from the menu bar:
Tools -> Index

> Process started: /usr/texbin/makeindex "nomenclature".nlo -s
>   nomencl.ist -o "nomenclature".nls
>
> This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2015] (kpathsea + Thai
>   support). Scanning style file
>   /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/makeindex/nomencl/nomencl.ist..........done
>   (10 attributes redefined, 3 ignored). Scanning input file
>   nomenclature.nlo....done (5 entries accepted, 0 rejected). Sorting
>   entries....done (13 comparisons). Generating output file
>   nomenclature.nls....done (16 lines written, 0 warnings). Output
>   written in nomenclature.nls. Transcript written in nomenclature.ilg.
>
> Process exited normally

Comment: This configuration will make it impossible, to compile a normal index.  What you should have done is to add an user defined command, which can be done in the "Build" tab of the image shown above.

Answer (score 1):

After writing the commands in Latex, go to
Options -> Configure TexStudio -> Build (on your left side) -> User Commands (on your right side)

In the box, type the following
**makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls -t %.nlg**
and save it.
Then run the file two times

Answer (score 0):

1. Run Latex in Kile
2. Go to Konsole (in Kile) and run 'makeindex filename.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o filename.nls' (without the quotes)
3. Run Latex again
4. DVItoPS
5. PStoPdf
   In other GUIs do this. It works