# Why my printnomenclature not working?

Tags: acronyms, nomenclature

This is my Script:
 In my class file i added the following entry:

```
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl} 
\renewcommand{\nomname}{\large \textbf{Mathematical Notation}}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
Acronym,Description
LED,Light emitting diode
FET,Field effect transistor
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{acronyms}{test.csv}

\DTLsort{Acronym}{acronyms}
```

In my acronym.tex file I had this entry:

```
\chapter*{Terminology / Notation}
\section*{\large \textbf{Acronyms / Abbreviations}}

\begin{itemize}

\DTLforeach*{acronyms}{\thisAcronym=Acronym,\thisDesc=Description}%
  {\item \textbf{\thisAcronym} \thisDesc}%
\end{itemize}
\printnomenclature
```

In my Chapter1:

```
$\gamma = \int_1^\infty\left({1\over\lfloor x\rfloor}
-{1\over x}\right)\,dx$
\nomenclature{$\gamma$}{Euler–Mascheroni constant\nomrefpage}
```

In my Main tex file:

```
\begin{document}
\include{Acronyms/acronyms}
\end{document}
```

Actually, I am expecting the Acronym and Nomenclature should be under the same "Terminology/Notation" but should be printed in separate page. Because i don't want to use glossary stuff as its quite complicated to compile in windows under Texlipse..So i used datatool package where we can specify list of acronyms which can be saved to csv and written back to pdf*. Also i wanted to use nomenclature because of having equations in my report..If we use independently the nomenclature package its working fine..but when i use \printnomenclature in acrnonym.tex file nomenclature is not getting printed..Any helps?

Comment: When creating a MWE, please try to make one single file, that other users can copy and compile in order to reproduce your problem. If you need more external files (e.g. because your problem actually _is_ about external files), using `filecontents*` is the right way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably missing the necessary makeindex run ([related question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27824/using-package-nomencl)). The following MWE using your excerpts works fine for me -- I recommend using latexmk and an appropriate .latexmkrc to make this easier:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl} 
\renewcommand{\nomname}{\large \textbf{Mathematical Notation}}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
Acronym,Description
LED,Light emitting diode
FET,Field effect transistor
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{acronyms.tex}
\chapter*{Terminology / Notation}
\section*{\large \textbf{Acronyms / Abbreviations}}
\begin{itemize}
\DTLforeach*{acronyms}{\thisAcronym=Acronym,\thisDesc=Description}%
  {\item \textbf{\thisAcronym} \thisDesc}%
\end{itemize}
\printnomenclature
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{acronyms}{test.csv}
\DTLsort{Acronym}{acronyms}
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
This document works fine as long as you run the right \verb|makeindex| command.
It may be easiest to use \verb|latexmk| with the following lines in a file named
\verb|.latexmkrc| or \verb|latexmkrc| in the same directory as the .tex files.
\begin{verbatim}
add_cus_dep("nlo", "nls", 0, "nlo2nls");
sub nlo2nls {
    system("makeindex $_[0].nlo -s nomencl.ist -o $_[0].nls -t $_[0].nlg");
}
\end{verbatim}
$\gamma = \int_1^\infty\left({1\over\lfloor x\rfloor}
-{1\over x}\right)\,dx$
\nomenclature{$\gamma$}{Euler-Mascheroni constant\nomrefpage}
\include{acronyms}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you are genius..Thanks a lot..it worked for me..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, to solve it I downloaded the `nomencl.ist` fine from internet, placed it in the working directory, changed the makeindex command to search for this file (that is, `./nomencl.ist`) and that was it, the compilation proceeded without problems.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, the nls file was empty, this is why it compiled, but then I figured it out, I cleaned all auxiliary files (that is everything except the *.tex source) and then it worked. It seems that a preexisting *.nlo file (or maybe some other) causes the error notification.