# How to include notation using nomencl in document?

Tags: nomenclature

I've been trying to use the `nomencl` package to start a table of notation. I'm using the example code included in the documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
\section*{Main equations}
\begin{equation}
a=\frac{N}{A}
\end{equation}%
\nomenclature{$a$}{The number of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$N$}{The number of angels per needle point}%
\nomenclature{$A$}{The area of the needle point}%
The equation $\sigma = m a$%
\nomenclature{$\sigma$}{The total mass of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$m$}{The mass of one angel}
follows easily.
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

I see this produces the `.nlo` file as it should, but I can't run it. I gather according to the manual I'm supposed to run a command, but how do I go about doing this - I'm running Windows 7 with TeX Live 2011.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`nomencl` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nomencl/nomencl.pdf) states that you have to run

```
makeindex <filename>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <filename>.nls
```

(from the command line, or as part of your editor workflow) which produces a `.nls` file, which is used by `\printnomenclature`. In fact, [`nomencl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl) defines

```
\def\@outputfileextension{.nlo}%
\def\@inputfileextension{.nls}%
```

to be the respective output and input file extensions. The former is created via `\makenomenclature`, while the latter is used by `\printnomenclature`.

Comment: How would I go about adding that to the editor workflow? (i'm using TeXworks) This is the first thing i've had to execute outside of TeX, so I'm not really sure of the procedure.

Comment: @Andy: I have not worked with TeXworks (I've used TeXnicCenter for this), but will try to look into this tonight.

Comment: @Andy, If you do not mind using some other editor for this purpose, Try a shareware `winedt` from winedt.com. It has this facility (TeX->Make Nomencl). Winedt is a shareware, but you can use it.

Comment: @Werner I'd go with `latexmk`. Example `.latexmkrc` given in [this other answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43141/3345).

Answer (score 2):

Adding some more details on Werner's answer, I would like to mention that one has to run this command from the folder where the `yourfile.nlo` is situated. Otherwise it is better to give the full path of `yourfile.nlo` (just in case your folder is not in system path).

```
makeindex E:\path..\yourfile.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o E:\path..\yourfile.nls
```

Then run pdflatex again (preferably 2 times).

Answer (score 2):

[Credit for this answer goes to Joseph Wright](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2008-03/msg01118.html).

You can force the makeindex from the .text file (tested it in WinEdt 8 and Tex) by adding \write18 as a first line.

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
\section*{Main equations}
\begin{equation}
a=\frac{N}{A}
\end{equation}%
\nomenclature{$a$}{The number of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$N$}{The number of angels per needle point}%
\nomenclature{$A$}{The area of the needle point}%
The equation $\sigma = m a$%
\nomenclature{$\sigma$}{The total mass of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$m$}{The mass of one angel}
follows easily.
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```