# MiKTeX, nomencl - Couldn't find input index file

Tags: miktex, auxiliary-files, nomenclature

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using package nomencl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27824/using-package-nomencl)

I was searching for this problem on this webpage and I found several related questions, however, with no accepted answer. I hope this entry will help others to solve the problem quickly in the future.

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 with package `nomencl`, on Windows 7. I was trying to make a abbreviation list but I was facing this error when trying to invoke make index:

```
Couldn't find input index file MYFILE nor MYFILE.idx
```

This part of my previous LaTeX code is relevant:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

%list of abbreviations
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents % Include a table of contents

\newpage % Begins the essay on a new page instead of on the same page as the table of contents

\printnomenclature
\newpage 
\section{Introduction} % Major section

Every Global Navigation Satellite System (GNSS)\nomenclature{GNSS}{Global Navigation Satellite System}, as GPS\nomenclature{GPS}{Global Positioning System}, GLONASS and
```

PdfLaTeX does no error and *"the nomenclature file `<filename>.nlo` corre-sponding to your LATEX file `<filename>.tex` and to write the information from your `\nomenclature` commands to this file"* as it is written in  [A Package to Create a Nomenclature - page 2](http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nomencl/nomencl.pdf).

The next step, to run MakeIndex produces error:

```
Couldn't find input index file MYFILE nor MYFILE.idx
```

end no abbreviation list is created. The next step according to the manual is to run

```
"makeindex <filename>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <filename>.nls"
```

But How?

Comment: If your file is `master.tex`, then the command line must be `makeindex master.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o master.nls`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to do 2 things to accomplish it:

1. to write `\makeindex` in the document preamble:

   ```
   %list of abbreviations
   \usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
   \makenomenclature

   \makeindex % <=== !!!!!
   \begin{document}
   ```

   And run the pdFLaTeX again
2. to use windows command prompt to execute the `makeindex <filename>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <filename>.nls` command:

   Run the CMD and get to the folder of the your article files. Write the command above with your file names. By doing that you will obtain desirable `.nls` file. My output is:
   [image: My output is:]

Run the pdfLaTeX again to create the list in the document.