# latexmk and nomencl

Tags: latexmk, nomenclature

I'm trying to implement the `nomencl` package in my Master's thesis, but I'm experiencing serious trouble when it comes to make `latexmk`/`makeindex` create or update the `nls` file. I ended up creating the `nls` file manually from terminal (according to the `nomencl` documentation), but it won't update. I'm using TeX Live and Sublime Text 2 with LaTeXTools.

So, according to quite wide web I'm not the only one having troubles making `nomencl` and `latexmk`/`makeindex` communicate properly. According to one thread, I tried to add the following code to a `latexmkrc` file:

```
# for nomenclature
add_cus_dep("nlo", "nls", 0, "nlo2nls");
sub nlo2nls {
    system("makeindex $_[0].nlo -s nomencl.ist -o $_[0].nls -t $_[0].nlg");
}
```

I found no less than 8 `latexmkrc` files on my Mac, none of them located according to the `latexmk` documentation, and with no response to `print('Hello, world!');` added to any of the files. I also tried to make a `latexmkrc` file in `/opt/local/share/latexmk/LatexmK` (and `/opt/local/share/latexmk`, just in case). Neither responds to

```
Hello, world!
```

My question is: how do I get the `nls` file to be created and updated automatically?

Comment: As @texenthusiast writes in his answer, a good place to put a configuration like this is in a file named `.latexmkrc` in your home directory.  But I think you may have misunderstood the documentation for the names of the system-wide configuration files.  These are files named LatexMk in one of the directories /opt/local/share/latexmk/ /usr/local/share/latexmk/ /usr/local/lib/latexmk/  (There are some backwards compatibility reasons for the naming.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I obviously misunderstood!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just in case you want `latexmk`, the first step is to verify your current version with `latexmk -v` at the command line/terminal; current version is 4.35, dated 11 Nov 2012. Otherwise update your TeXlive distribution or update to the latest via [latexmk at ctan](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexmk).

Add the custom dependency commands depending on your requirements in a `.latexmkrc` file in your home directory using Terminal (Linux). For your `nomencl` example see [examplerc scripts](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexmk/example_rcfiles/pdflatexmkrc) at ctan

```
  gedit $HOME/.latexmkrc
```

with the following contents

```
 # Custom dependency and function for nomencl package 
 add_cus_dep( 'nlo', 'nls', 0, 'makenlo2nls' );
 sub makenlo2nls {
 system( "makeindex -s nomencl.ist -o \"$_[0].nls\" \"$_[0].nlo\"" );
 }
```

Then it should work with `latexmk`, it worked for me at least.

Comment: Awesome! This solved my problem. My version of `latexmk` was up to date, but the `gedit` code obviously created a `.latexmkrc` file that `latexmk` was able to find. Thanks! =)

Comment: this also helped me! i was already using latexmk, so i just added this above my existing .latexmkrc contents (which were as follows)

`$pdflatex = "xelatex %O %S"; $pdf_mode = 1; $dvi_mode = $postscript_mode = 0;`

Answer (score 7):

If you can, I suggest you to try [arara](https://github.com/cereda/arara).

## Advantages:

1. It has a great manual written for humans ;-)
2. You can use directives from within the document, meaning that you can compile different documents in different ways. In other words, the directives are document specific.
3. Comiplation is easy and one step: `arara yourfile`
4. The documentation tells you about integrating arara to get a one click toolbar button in many editors. Hence you can run arara from within your editor.
5. It comes shipped with texlive.
6. ....
7. ......

Here is a sample file (say `myfile.tex`):

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: { overwrite: false, output: outputfile.tex, trace: true }

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\printnomenclature

\chapter{Structural Analysis} \label{sec:Structural Analysis}
\section{Sectional Properties} \label{sec:Sectional Properties}

The cross-sectional area is defined as
\begin{equation} \label{eqn:Cross-sectional area}
    A = \int_{S} \, dS
\end{equation}
\nomenclature{$A$}{cross-sectional area, m$^{2}$}
\nomenclature{$S$}{arbitrary surface}

\chapter{Structural Analysis} \label{sec:Structural Analysis2}
\section{Sectional Properties} \label{sec:Sectional Properties2}
The cross-sectional area is defined as
\begin{equation} \label{eqn:Cross-sectional area2}
    A = \int_{S} \, dS
\end{equation}
\nomenclature{$A2$}{cross-sectional area, m$^{2}$}
\nomenclature{$S2$}{arbitrary surface}

\end{document}
```

Compile this with `arara myfile`. For further details, consult the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/support/arara/arara-usermanual.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though this is not the kind of solution I was looking for. That was supplied by @texenthusiast =)

Comment: @Holene No problem. I just wanted to make you aware of arara :-).

Comment: This helped me plentiful - thx. ;)