# Input index file .idx not found

Tags: texstudio, nomencl

I know this is a question that has been asked in many forms and I should find a solution out there, but I am simply not able to.

I am using Texstudio to type a document. I have the following in my preamble:

```
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makenomenclature
```

With various nomenclature entries, for example:

```
\nomenclature{$T$}{Test}
```

I then have this within the document environment:

```
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\printnomenclature
```

I then do a latexmk followed by the Makeindex sequence. The document compiles but without the nomenclature.

This error prints to the console: `Input index file filename.idx not found. Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]`

where 'filename' is the name of my Latex document.

I interpret this as I have to run the `makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]` command to create the `.idx` file. But I have no idea to actually run this command.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give a full example, but from what I can see `makeindex` attempts to run an index input file with extension `.idx` that usually would be created from the `\makeindex` command of the `makeidx` package. This is what you usually do for indices. However, you are trying to set a nomenclature which also uses `makeindex` as backend but uses different input files, i.e. files with the extension `.nlo`.

So you could either

- run the appropriate command for making the nomenclature by hand: `makeindex filename.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o filename.nls`,
- add a command to TeXstudio that runs it for you, as explained in [Makeindex no .nls file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161304/makeindex-no-nls-file), or
- configure `latexmk` to process the `.nlo` file as explained in [latexmk and nomencl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105943/latexmk-and-nomencl).