# Nomenclature does not appear

Tags: nomenclature

I can't create a list of abbreviations. I have been using `nomencl` package.

I put `\makenomenclature` and

```
\nomenclature{symbol}{name of symbol}
\printnomenclature
```

But nomenclature doesn't appear.

Thanks

Comment: Have you run `makeindex`? See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27824/using-package-nomencl/27826#27826

Comment: I don't understand this. how I can run that code ?

Comment: @user46548 Which operating system do you use?

Comment: See [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/18dZp.png) to see how to configure texworks to work.

Comment: I use windows 8. I have install winedit and miktek in my pc,