# How to create nomenclature using TeXnicCenter?

Tags: texniccenter, nomenclature

I have trouble executing the nomenclature. I saw many posts in the internet like [Using package nomencl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27824/using-package-nomencl) and [List of symbols or abbreviations (nomenclature)](http://texblog.org/2012/05/14/list-of-symbols-or-abbreviations-nomenclature/) but I am unable to do it.

I would like to create a list of symbols to my report that I am writing. I am using Windows 7 and TeXnicCenter. I do not know what these sequences mean?

```
latex filename.tex
makeindex filename.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o filename.nls
latex filename.tex
```

Any help please? What should I do?

Comment: Those are the commands you enter at the command line although your editor probably has a button you use to compile the basic document (`(pdf)latex filename.tex`). If you can't run the `makeindex` line using your editor, use the command line or configure your editor appropriately. Somehow or other, you need to run those commands.

Comment: I never try to compile `nomecl` in Windows, for me is more comfortable to do it in a `gnu/linux` terminal. But surely you could run those commands inside the command prompt. I don't use TeXnicCenter so I can't help you with the technical parts of your editor. Please read carefully the documentation of the `nomencl`package, there explains how to compile and get your lists correctly. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In TeXnicCenter you can add a new profile for compiling with a nomenclature.

Press alt+F7 to open the dialog windows for the profiles. Choose your standard profile, copy it with the button copy and give it a new name, like "LaTeX-PDF-nomencl".

Now check that you have clicked on register "(La)TeX". In the last line you can add your arguments to be given to `makeindex`: your arguments (see your command above) "filename.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o filename.nls" translate to ""%tm.nlo" -g –s nomencl.ist  -o “%tm.nls" then TeXnicCenter can work with it.

I have only a german version of TeXnicCenter here but I guess a screenshot will help you.

[image]

Don't forget to check the log file for errors or warnings for your nomenclature.

A little bit late this answer, but I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 2):

I quote the accepted answer, but for me (TeXnicCenter 2.02 (stable) 64bit, MiKTeX 2.9, Win 10) the option -g was not correct. To get the Nomenclature page printed, I edited the command line argument of Makeindex in the build output profile to be just:

```
%tm.nlo" -s nomencl.ist -o "%tm.nls"
```

Cheers.

Comment: I believe the -g was recommended in the docs for German users, so yes this is correct.

Comment: There is some " missing in the beginning.