# problem with elsarticle and nomenclature

Tags: nomenclature, elsarticle

hello please i try the nomenclature with elsarticle but it doesn't work. Could help please. Thank you

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{framed} % Framing content
\usepackage{multicol} % Multiple columns environment

\usepackage{nomencl} % Nomenclature package
\makenomenclature
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parskip} % Baseline skip between items

\renewcommand*\nompreamble{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\renewcommand*\nompostamble{\end{multicols}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!t]
   \begin{framed}
     \printnomenclature
  \end{table*}
\nomenclature{$I_b$}{First item}
\nomenclature{$I_d$}{Second item}
\nomenclature{$I_r$}{Third item}
 \end{framed}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by  "wostrong textrk"?

Answer (score 1):

Your MWE causes the error

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{framed} on input line 14 ended by \end{table*}.
```

which means the environments aren't correctly nested. Move `\end{framed}` before `\end{table*}`:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{framed} % Framing content
\usepackage{multicol} % Multiple columns environment

\usepackage{nomencl} % Nomenclature package
\makenomenclature
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parskip} % Baseline skip between items

\renewcommand*\nompreamble{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\renewcommand*\nompostamble{\end{multicols}}
\begin{document}
Test.

\begin{table*}[!t]
   \begin{framed}
     \printnomenclature
   \end{framed}
\end{table*}
\nomenclature{$I_b$}{First item}
\nomenclature{$I_d$}{Second item}
\nomenclature{$I_r$}{Third item}

\end{document}
```

Remember that the document build requires a call to the `makeindex` application, as described in [Using package nomencl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27824).

Comment: thank you it works for me using makeindex <filename>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <filename>.nls not makeindex <filename>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <filename>.els

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Nothing !  i dont know where is the problem

Comment: This area is reserved for answers. You can edit your question to add further information.