# Nomenclature not working

Tags: nomenclature

Trying to print my nomenclature in my document.
I am not sure where to put the `\makenomenclature` and `\printnomenclature` command. Tried several things, but they are not working. The question is: where to put these commands, so that the nomenclature is correctly compiled?

I am using the following preamble (with university report style):

```
\documentclass{undefineduniversity-report}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx} %allow SI units
\usepackage{cleveref} %smart referencing, automatic sorting etc.
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature 

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References} %rename bibliography --> references

%% Use Roman numerals for the page numbers of the title pages and table of
%% contents.
\frontmatter

\title[ ]{Development of Siliconoxide as Electron Selective Passivating \\ Contact Layer in Silicon \\ Heterjunction Solar Cells}
\author{}
\affiliation{}
\coverimage{thesiscover.png}
\makecover

%% Include an optional title page.
\input{titlepage}

\input{abstract}

\input{nomenclature/nomenclature}

\tableofcontents

%% Use Arabic numerals for the page numbers of the chapters.
\mainmatter


\mainmatter % from here the arabic number starts

\input{chapters/introduction/introduction}
\input{chapters/background/background}
\input{chapters/methodology/methodology}
\input{chapters/results/results}
\input{chapters/discussion/discussion}
\input{chapters/conclusion/conclusion}
\input{chapters/acknowledgements/acknowledgements}


%% Use letters for the chapter numbers of the appendices.
\appendix

\input{appendix/appendix-a}
\input{appendix/appendix-b}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references}
```

\end{document}

I defined the nomenclature chapter as follows:

```
\chapter*{Nomenclature}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature}

\nomenclature{$J_{sc}$}{Short circuit current: current through the solar cell \\ when the voltage across the solar cell is zero}

\printnomenclature
```

Also, I am wondering how the nomenclature package lists its input (alphabetically or just in order you type them in the document).

Help is very much appreciated!!

Comment: What exactly is not working? You seemingly set up everything in the right order. The `nomenclature` package will sort the entries alphabetically.

Comment: Did you make sure you run `makeindex`? (`makeindex <filename>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <filename>.nls`)

Comment: Related: [Using package nomencl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27824)

Comment: @leandriis what do you mean with makeindex?  I think I did not run makeindex? I do run makenomenclature though..

Comment: @W.v.Ekeren: `makeindex` is a program that creates a sorted index from a raw data input. In the answers to the question  Nicola Talbot  has linked you can find information on how to use this program in combination with the `nomencl` package.

Comment: How do I make sure makeindex refers to the correct file directory? My nomenclature file is just named nomenclature, but the command cannot be started? I get the following error:

Error : could not start the command : <nomenclature>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <nomenclature>.nls